# Toggle between two divs or text using React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

First of all, I am new to React and Hooks.

What I would like to do is that when a state changes, so does a div or some text.

So for example:

```
const App = ( ) => {

    const [textToggle, textToggleState] = useState(true)

    return (

        <div>This is come text</div>
        <div>This is come extra text</div>
        <div onClick={ () => textToggleState(!textToggle) }>Click me</div>
    );
};

export default memo(App);
```

So in this case I have my toggle button, which will toggle between a true or false state. This I usually use do add/remove a class from a div, so for example:

```
<div className={textToggle ? "normal-class" : "super-class"}></div>
```

Or something similar to that. However, what I would like to achieve is to change between showing the two first divs in the above code, or just add the word `extra` in the first when ever the toggle is initiated.

I am not quite sure how to achieve this, and if it even should be made with the `useState` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you just want to show/hide each div accordingly, try this

```
{textToggle && <div>This is come text</div>}
{!textToggle && <div>This is come extra text</div>}
```

or simplified

```
{
 textToggle ?
  <div>This is come text</div>
 :
  <div>This is come extra text</div>
}
```

if you want to add the `extra` text then try this

```
<div>This is come {textToggle ? "" : "extra"} text</div>
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know it could be used this way. Excellent.